# glide with androidsvg sample not loading URL

Tags: java, android, androidsvg, android-glide

I am trying to add the ability to set an ImageView to an SVG using Glide and AndroidSVG (https://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/).

I am using the sample from Glide: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/v4.10.0/samples/svg

I am using Glide 4.10.0

I am getting "onLoadFailed".  The error just simply says that it can not load the resource, it does not indicate why.

Here is the code where I am calling Glide to load the SVG

```
GlideUrl glideUrl = .....

Glide.with(thumbnailImageView.getContext())
    .as(PictureDrawable.class)
    .load(glideUrl)

    .placeholder(R.color.file_placeholder)
    .listener(new RequestListener<PictureDrawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model,
                                    Target<PictureDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            DataWorkflowTasks.log("thumbnail load failed!" + e.getMessage());

            ImageView view = ((ImageViewTarget<?>) target).getView();
            view.setLayerType(ImageView.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
            
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(PictureDrawable resource, Object model,
                                       Target<PictureDrawable> target, DataSource dataSource,
                                       boolean isFirstResource) {
            ImageView view = ((ImageViewTarget<?>) target).getView();
            view.setLayerType(ImageView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

            //on load success
            return false;
        }
    })
    .into(thumbnailImageView);
```

In the same package I have the following which are EXACT copies from the Glide 4.10.0 sample.

- SvgDecoder
- SvgDrawableTranscoder
- SvgModule

The SVG I am testing with is the following file https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/410.svg

I am wondering if i have not set up Glide correctly so its not picking up the SvgDecoder/SvgDrawableTranscoder/SvgModule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expected I had not set up Glide correctly. I was missing this line in my build.gradle file:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.14.2'
```

Furthermore my Glide command should have been using "GlideApp" not "Glide", this is so that is uses the  extra Glide files (SvgDecoder/SvgModule/SvgDrawableTranscoder) handling the SVG file.

I also had to comment out the placeholder image otherwise i was getting an error about bitmap missing the src attribute.

Glide.with(thumbnailImageView.getContext())
.as(PictureDrawable.class)
.load(glideUrl)

```
.listener(new RequestListener<PictureDrawable>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model,
                                Target<PictureDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
        DataWorkflowTasks.log("thumbnail load failed!" + e.getMessage());

        ImageView view = ((ImageViewTarget<?>) target).getView();
        view.setLayerType(ImageView.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
        
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onResourceReady(PictureDrawable resource, Object model,
                                   Target<PictureDrawable> target, DataSource dataSource,
                                   boolean isFirstResource) {
        ImageView view = ((ImageViewTarget<?>) target).getView();
        view.setLayerType(ImageView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

        //on load success
        return false;
    }
})
.into(thumbnailImageView);
```